# Failure during installation of Ubuntu Phone

Tags: phone, nexus-4

After executing

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
```

to install Ubuntu on my Nexus 4, the error message comes up

```
mkdir /root/.cache: permission denied
```

Comment: Hi David, the command  ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap  is direct accessing the phone. There is no way to do a Sudo Su (see installation instraction https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/?_ga=1.211364117.1887161752.1488727407)

Answer (score 0):

found the problem - I was as root user in the terminal (sudo su). After try to install it as "normal" user it worked.