# How to install Ubuntu Touch on Moto X First Gen?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, phone

I have a Moto X First Gen and I want to use Ubuntu on it.  I have already unlocked the bootloader, but I can't figure out how to do the rest.  I also have all of the adb and fastboot stuff installed on my laptop.  I followed the instructions here

[Installing Ubuntu for Devices](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)

But it stopped working when it told me to run this command.

```
$ ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
```

Comment: Refer to this thread, it could be helpful: [failure during installation of ubuntu phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889895/failure-during-installation-of-ubuntu-phone)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help.  I think it might have something to do with the type of device I have.

Comment: Please provide detailed information about errors, and logs present in the process. So we can debug the problem faster.

Comment: @GTRONICK after running the aforementioned command, it says `2017/05/02 16:25:53 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting` and does nothing.

Comment: This seems to be a bug: [Waiting for device](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phablet-tools/+bug/1455050)

Comment: Due to the fact that Touch is no longer under support or going to receive any updates, I would seriously consider not doing this until someone takes the code on and starts running with it.

Comment: @PhilUK Well I do want to do this.  _you_ don't have to if you don't want to, but I would like some help with this.

Comment: @Curtice Gough Well that is up to you. I do not need to as I was one of the ones who brought three tablets and a phone. All in the hope of supporting Ubuntu so they would develop this product further.You can do what you want, it does not bother me, I was just trying to give a practical view of the support prospects.